# infinite turning points without trig....possible?

Tags: analysis

Is it possible to make a function with INFINITE turning points using ONLY

REAL exponentials (and logs)
REAL powers of x
powers,roots, sums, products, quotients, compositions etc of the above

(NO trigs, piecewise, mod)

My feeling is not on the grounds that such a function could be broken down into smaller units each of which will only have a finite number of TP and as such a combination of finite TP cannot produce infinite TP. Can anyone suggest a formal approach which I can use as a starting point

Thanks for your views.

Comment: $f(x) = 0.\hphantom{}$

Comment: @Ennar That's clearly cheating. Any other examples?

Comment: @Matt Samuel, sure if you'll let piecewise defined functions. But if you insist on $f = f_1\circ\ldots \circ f_n$, where $f_i$ is elementary, non-constant, non-trigonometric, then no, by induction.

Comment: @Ennar I think that last one is what the op is looking for.

Comment: Ennar, that's just trivial and cheating (in a nice way!). Let's have a proper 'meaty' equation or a path to get started on a proof that it is not possible.

Comment: Matt Samuel.....piecewise not so good but do tell me more about getting started on an induction proof as this appeals to me.

Comment: Quadratica, you prove by induction a stronger statement, that finite composition of elementary functions, excluding trigonometric and constants, can hit any value only finitely many times.

Comment: Yes, I see....I could consider just two elementary functions as as starting point, prove they only hit a single value a finite number of times and then introduce a third function and combine it with the first two and so on...is that right ?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ and $g$ can hit any value only finitely many times, the only work is to show that the same holds for $g\circ f$. Since you want a function $f = f_1\circ\ldots\circ f_n$, where $f_i$ is from your list, the induction is clear from there.

Comment: I will follow this up as it sounds very right. Thank  you for your advice Ennar.

Comment: @Ennar: your approach doesn't work as you are allowed to combine the functions algebraically rather than just by composition. E.g., take $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = -x $ and $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$.

Comment: I assume induction can also be used to prove that an algebraic combination (of the functions listed) also cannot lead to inf distinct roots

Comment: @Rob, you are right, but you could include those as functions as well, so it's still a composition. One would just have to again exclude compositions that simplify to constants, but it's more involved.

Comment: @Rob:  composition is less important as any composed function is easily formed by (listed) functions. Can you throw some light on proving that a finite (algebraic) combination cannot have inf distinct roots.

Comment: @Ennar I think it'd avoid special cases if you say that whenever it takes on a value infinitely many times it is a constant identically equal to that value.

Comment: Thanks people, I have enough to get started on a proof and will go with the induction approach as it sounds plausible and reasonably straightforward.

Comment: I doubt that this question has an easy answer. It is a (hard) result in model theory that the [exponential field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field) $\Bbb{R}_{\exp}$ is [o-minimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory). This means that a set definable in your theory is a finite union of points and intervals (possibly with endpoints at $\pm\infty$). You are only interested in sets defined by one equation, but you allow partial functions like $\log$, etc.  I guess it would take a lot of work to formulate and prove a precise conjecture of the sort you want.

Comment: I think it does have an easy answer...the answer is clearly NO. There is no way to combine functions of the listed type to produce distinct inf roots. Proving such may be an obstacle. If the equation is reducible to the form f+g+h....and each f,g,h has finite roots then is it correct to deduce that f+g+...will also have finite roots ?

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$ both have exactly one root but $h(x) = f(x) + g(x) = 0$ has infinitely many roots. So first of all, you need to come up with a true conjecture.

Comment: You're right. I have not been clear enough. I don't want a function that is identically equal to zero for all x....such as your example. In my equation the values oscillate (zero derivative between roots). In such a case would my statement be true?

Comment: I have amended my question so turning points replaces roots.

Comment: Your statement about turning points (or maybe crossing points) is true by dint of o-minimality. See the links in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for replies, I will investigate. Time for sleep now (UK) but any further replies from users are most welcome and appreciated.

Comment: You mean *infinitely many* turning points (as opposed to an *infinite turning point*, whatever that would be).